# PHP Line Break not working

Tags: php, line-breaks

I am learning php and am making a statement that proves the local variable cannot be called outside a function where it is defined.

I can't seem to get a line break come out in the statement but only a line space.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Global and Local Variables</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

//Global varaible called after function
$g_test_string="this is the value in the variable outside the function at a global level!";

function printstring()
{
$l_test_string="this is the value of the variable inside the function at a local level!";
print($l_test_string);
}

//Calling statements

printstring();
echo "\r";
echo 'Global variable value: ' . $g_test_string;
echo 'Local variable value: ' . $l_test_string;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The print out looks like this:

```
this is the value of the variable inside the function at a local level! Global variable value: this is the value in the variable outside the function at a global level! Local variable value:
```

I tried a break between the function call and echo for global variable but only produces a line space not a break.

Got to be something simple I imagine.

Many thanks

Andrew

Comment: Look at your page & view source, your line break will be there, it's just not being rendered as you imagine. Either do `echo "<br>"` instead of `"\r"`, or just precede your output with a `<pre>` tag

Comment: if you try to use \n you have to use double quote:
"\n" 
\n doas not work in '\n'

Comment: To elaborate on the comment above, "does not work" means that PHP will not parse it. Anything in single quotes is treated literally while items inside double quotes gets parsed so that "\n" becomes a newline and "\r" becomes a return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure your line break is cross platform compatible, use `PHP_EOL` I usually use "\n". If you want the linebreak to appear in HTML, use `"<br>"`.

Edit in response to comments:
Here's how you pull as much PHP out of the HTML as possible.

```
<?php 

//Global varaible called after function
$g_test_string="this is the value in the variable outside the function at a global level!";
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Global and Local Variables</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//Calling statements

printstring();
echo "<br>\n";
echo 'Global variable value: ' . $g_test_string."<br>\n";

echo 'Local variable value: ' . $l_test_string."<br>\n";
?>    
</body>
</html>

<?php
  function printstring()
  {
    $l_test_string="this is the value of the variable inside the function at a local level!";
    print($l_test_string);
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the function outside the HTML and call the function from inside the HTML. If so what statement for line break would you use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. PHP happens on the server. It does "stuff" and then outputs text (usually HTML). I'll commonly do something like `<div>Here's some text with <?php echo 'Some generated text with linebreak<br>'."\n"; ?>This is on the next line in both the browser and the source.</div>`

Comment: Due to my ignorance with PHP I am probably asking the wrong question but I'm thinking along the lines of the way CSS is set up with all the CSS statements in one file and the call to the classes in the HTML.

Comment: This is leading into a discussion that is more than SO likes to have in comments. It looks like you'd do well to spend some time at php.net and just read a bunch of questions and answers here as well. To answer your last comment question though, you're talking about `include()` or `require()`

Answer (score 1):

Where you want a line break in PHP use either `<br />` or `\n`

I used breaklines for your demo: http://www.forumalliance.net/so.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Global and Local Variables</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

//Global varaible called after function
$g_test_string="this is the value in the variable outside the function at a global level!<br />";

function printstring()
{
$l_test_string="this is the value of the variable inside the function at a local level!<br />";
print($l_test_string);
}

//Calling statements

printstring();
echo "\r";
echo '<br />Global variable value: ' . $g_test_string;
echo '<br />Local variable value: ' . $l_test_string;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's intentional `I am learning php and am making a statement that proves the local variable cannot be called outside a function where it is defined.`

Comment: Ok, seems good. If this helped then be sure to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: So I don't need to use echo "\r" after the call to function but use <br> after text for varaible?

Answer (score 0):

How break the line on display data one by one line on while loop  and forward to dropdown  id

```
$que="select * from parties  WHERE Item_code='".$_GET['q']."'";

$run=mysql_query($que);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){    
  if($row['party_name'] == "")
  {
    echo "";
  }

  else
  {
    if($_GET['type'] == "di")    
    {
      echo $row['Id'];      
    }    
    elseif($_GET['type'] == "did")
    {    
      echo  $row['party_name'];     
    }//END IF DI OR DID    
  }//END IF PARTY NAME BLANK    
}//END WHILE
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround if you are trying to print `"\n"` on your localhost, try adding following in your script on the top.

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

Not an ideal solution but works.